# fatal error: linux/delay.h: No such file or directory

Tags: c, linux, delay

The function `mdelay()` is used in my program, but when compiling, GCC gave me an error:

> fatal error: linux/delay.h: No such file or directory

I tried to solve this problem, but nothing worked.

What I've tried:

- copy the file, delay.h, into the folder /usr/linux, but it'll show up another header file (asm/delay.h) missing.
- copy the file, delay.h (different from the above), into the folder /usr/asm, but it'll show up many header files missing.

How to solve this problem?

Envir: Ubuntu 12.04 LTS

Comment: Exactly what are you trying to build? As I see it, you want to build something against the source of the Linux kernel (e.g. a driver). Is that right?

Comment: @evnu Not a driver, I just want my simple C code to delay a short time as what I used (`Sleep()`) in Windows.

Comment: use `sleep` of `usleep`

Comment: @sujin I've tried to use `msleep()` before, but that is different from Sleep().

Comment: @KevinDongNaiJia: Which `msleep()` function? I'd go with `usleep()` as well and just scale the parameter to microseconds.

Comment: Include files under `linux/` are for building the Linux kernel. They are of no use to you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As shown in the [Linux Cross Reference](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/include/linux/delay.h#L31), `mdelay()` is a macro within the linux kernel source code.

```
#ifndef mdelay
#define mdelay(n) (\
        (__builtin_constant_p(n) && (n)<=MAX_UDELAY_MS) ? udelay((n)*1000) : \
        ({unsigned long __ms=(n); while (__ms--) udelay(1000);}))
#endif
```

Thus, you cannot simply use it. But there exist multiple alternatives, e.g.:

- `sleep()` in `unistd.h` for sleeping `N` seconds.
- `usleep()` in `unistd.h` for sleeping `U` microseconds
- `nanosleep()` in `time.h` for making a thread sleep some nanoseconds.

As I understand, you are searching for a function to specify a microseconds sleep interval. Thus, use `usleep()`. Note however that the function is marked as *deprecated* with POSIX.1-2001. The manpage for `usleep()` advices to use `nanosleep()` instead.

Answer (score 1):

`msleep` is kernel function. If you want delay from `c` program use `sleep` or `usleep`.

I didn't found any `msleep` standard function. You can implement it by the help of `usleep`.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int main(void)
{
    long x = 1000000;
    sleep(1);  //1sec
    usleep(1); //1usec
    usleep(x); //1sec
    x = 1000;
    usleep(x); //1msec
    return 0;
}
```